# Best Practice for Restoring Both S3 and DynamoDB Together

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

One of the things I see becoming more of a problem in micro-service architecture is disaster recovery. For instance, a common pattern is to store large data objects in S3 such as multimedia data, whilst JSON data would go in DynamoDB. But what happens when you have a hacker come and manages to delete a whole buck of data from your DynamoDB?

You also need to make sure your S3 bucket is restored to the same state is was at that time but are there elegant ways of doing this? The concern is that it will be difficult to guarantee that both the S3 backup and the DynamoDB database are in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a solution to do a genuine synchronised backup-restore across services. However you could use the native [DynamoDB point in time restore](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/backup-restore/) and the third party [S3-pit-restore](https://github.com/madisoft/s3-pit-restore) library to restore both services to a common point in time.